# Error de ejecución al leer datos de FireStore en Android Studio

Tags: android, base-de-datos

Me encuentro realizando una **lectura** de los datos que tengo en la base de datos **firestore** para colocarlos en un **Recycler View** pero cuando ejecuto la aplicación, obtengo el siguiente error:

**Caused by:** *java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.collection(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference*

El error me lo marca en esta **línea de código**:
*db.collection("Usuarios").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {*

Les comparto el código de mi **Main Activity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText et_nombre, et_apellido;
private Button bt_guardar;
private RecyclerView recycler_resultados;

private ArrayList<model_recycler_resultados> al = new ArrayList<>();
private adapter_recycler_resultados adapter;

private FirebaseFirestore db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et_nombre = findViewById(R.id.et_nombre);
    et_apellido = findViewById(R.id.et_apellido);
    bt_guardar = findViewById(R.id.bt_guardar);
    recycler_resultados = findViewById(R.id.recycler_resultados);

    recycler_resultados.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mostrarDatos();
    adapter = new adapter_recycler_resultados(al);
    recycler_resultados.setAdapter(adapter);

    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
 }
 //MÉTODO PARA CONSULTAR DATOS
public void mostrarDatos(){
    al.clear();

   //LÍNEA LA CUAL GENERA EL ERROR
    db.collection("Usuarios").get().addOnCompleteListener(new 
OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            for(DocumentSnapshot ds : task.getResult()){
                model_recycler_resultados model = new 
model_recycler_resultados(ds.getString("Nombre"), ds.getString("Apellido"));
                al.add(model);
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ha ocurrido un error con 
la lectura de datos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Desde ya, agradezco muchísimo su lectura.

Comment: Alguien que sepa?

Comment: Pudiste solucionar esto?. A mi me esta pasando lo mismo.
Saludos